# Creating virtual host on ubuntu linux 12.10

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I use tomcat 7.0.42 on Ubuntu Linux 12.10.
I point my browser to `http://localhost:8080/myapp`
Can I create a virtual host in ubuntu which would allow me to hit the same address as

```
http://myapp.com
```

Basically creating an alias for `localhost:8080/myapp` as `myapp.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open file

/etc/hosts

and add those lines:

```
127.0.0.1 myapp.com

127.0.0.1 www.myapp.com
```

this will tell the operation system not to look for myapp.com IP address but to use localhost instead.

Comment: I added this to hosts and restarted the system

127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 aB-PC
127.0.1.1:8080 local.com
127.0.1.1:8081 ucma.com

Doesn't work.

Comment: I used port numbers in host file. That was the reason it did not work. Thanks for the answer. It helped, but the original issue remains.

Comment: you can open a server on port 80 that will return an html page that include the tomcat in iframe
<html><body><iframe src="http://localhost:8080"></body></html>

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

open a new file, with .pac extention, those files are used by firefox to determine proxies, copy this to the content of the file:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (host=='www.myapp.com'){
        return 'PROXY 127.0.0.1:8080';
    }
    // All other domains should connect directly without a proxy
    return "DIRECT";
}
```

go to FF proxy settings under "url for automatic proxy configuration" and enter the path to that file.

Comment: i think it should  work for other browsers too read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config)